# Two forms going to same route

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I am trying to make a log in and sign up page for my project and everything is working perfectly but i encountered a bug, the problem is there are two forms on my front page one is shown by default and other is shown after a button is clicked whose display is blocked until the button is clicked, here is my ui photo [image]

now the problem is if there is some details filled in the login form and i clicked on "create new account" it still goes on the route which i specified for log in , this problem does not occurs if the login fields are empty .

Here is my HTML code:-

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/style.css">
    <title>Social Book</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="main">
        <div class="left_side">
            Socialbook
        </div>
        
        
        <!--  this is the dialog box for signing in-->

        
        <form class="right_side" id="sign_in" action="/sign"  method="post">
            <input class="right_side_items" id="item_1" type="text" placeholder="Enter email" name="email" required ></input>
            <div class="right_side_items" id="item_2"> 
                <input id="item_2_1" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" id="password_field" name="sign_in_password" required></input>
                <div id="item_2_2" class="eye_img"><img src="/icons/visibility.svg" alt="" onclick="eye()"></div>
                <div id="item_2_3" class="eye_img"><img src="/icons/visibility_off.svg" alt="" onclick="eye_off()"></div>
            </div>
            <button class="right_side_items" id="item_3">Log In</button>
            <div class="right_side_items" id="item_4">Forgotten password?</div>
            <div class="right_side_items" id="item_5"></div>
            <button class="right_side_items" id="item_6"  type="submit" onclick="new_account()">Create New Account</button>
        </form>

        
        
        <!--  this is the dialog box for signing up as a new user-->
        
        
        
        <form class="new_account_box" action="/signup" id="new_box" method="post">
            <div class="dialog_box">

                <div class="new_acccount_item" id="new_item_1">
                    <div id="item_1_1">Sign Up</div>
                    <div id="item_1_2" onclick="closed()"><img src="./icons/close.svg" alt=" "  ></div>
                </div>
                <div class="new_acccount_item" id="new_item_2">
                    <input class="names" id="first_name" placeholder="first name" name="name" required></input>
                    <input class="names" id="last_name"  placeholder="Surname" name="second_name" required></input>
                </div>
                <input class="input_fields" id="new_item_3"  placeholder="Mobile number or email address" name="phone" type="email" required></input>
                <input class="input_fields" id="new_item_4" placeholder="New Password" name="word" required></input>
                <div   class="new_acccount_item" id="new_item_5">
                    <div class="item_5_content" id="item_5_1">Date of birth</div>
                    <input type="date" class="input_fields" id="item_5_2" name="date" required></input>                
                </div>
                <div class="new_acccount_item" id="new_item_6">
                    <div id="item_6_1">Gender</div>
                    <div id="item_6_2">
                        <div class="item_6_2_content" id="item_6_2_1">
                            
                            <label class="gender">
                                <input type="radio" name="gender" required></input>
                                <span class="checkmark"> </span>
                            </label>
                            <div class="gender_text">Male</div>
                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="item_6_2_content" id="item_6_2_2">
                            <label class="gender">
                                <input type="radio" name="gender"></input>
                                <span class="checkmark"> </span>
                            </label>
                            <div class="gender_text">Female</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item_6_2_content" id="item_6_2_3">
                            <label class="gender">
                                <input type="radio" name="gender"></input>
                                <span class="checkmark"> </span>
                            </label>
                            <div class="gender_text">Custom</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit"  class="new_acccount_item" id="new_item_7">
                    <div id="button_text">Sign Up</div>
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
<script>

    document.getElementById("new_box").style.display = "none";
    // document.getElementById("item_2_2").style.display = "none";
    function closed(){
        document.getElementById("new_box").style.display = "none";
    }
    function new_account(){
        document.getElementById("new_box").style.display = "flex";
    }

    function eye(){
        document.getElementById("item_2_2").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("item_2_3").style.display = "flex";
        document.getElementById("item_2_1").type = "password";
        console.log('button clicked')
    }
    function eye_off(){
        console.log('button clicked2')
        document.getElementById("item_2_2").style.display = "flex";
        document.getElementById("item_2_3").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("item_2_1").type = "text";
    }

</script>
</html>
```

This is CSS code :-

```
body{
    margin: 0px;
}

.main{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 15%;
}

.left_side{
    color: #1877f2;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 7rem;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: 25%;
}

.right_side{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(6);
    height: 50vh;
    width: 55vh;
    align-self: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%), 0 8px 16px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);
}
.right_side_items{
    border-radius: 5px;
    /* border-color: #d9d9d9; */
}

#item_1{
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    height: 60%;
    background-color: #f1f3f4;
}
#item_2{
    width: 96%;
    margin: auto;
    height: 60%;
    background-color: #f1f3f4;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 90% 10%;
}

#item_2_1{
    background-color: #f1f3f4;
    border: 0px;
}

#item_2_2 {
    display: none;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
#item_2_3 {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.eye_img img{
    cursor: pointer;
}


#item_3{
    width: 93%;
    margin: auto;
    height: 75%;
    background-color: #1877f2;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 1rem;
    border: 0px;
}

#item_3:hover{
    background-color: #086bee;
}

#item_4{
    width: fit-content;
    display: flex;
    align-self: center;
    margin: auto;
    color: #1877f2;
}
#item_5{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
    height: fit-content;
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: 5%;
}
#item_6{
    background-color: #42b72a;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 900;
    width: 45%;
    height: 75%;
    margin-left: 30%;
    border-radius: 7px;
    border: 0px;
}

#item_6:hover{
    background-color: #30ce11;
}

input{
    padding-left: 5%;
    border: 2px solid #d9d9d9;
}
input[type=text]:focus {
    outline: none; 
    border: 2px solid #1877f2;
  }
input[type=password]:focus {
    outline: none; 
    border: 2px solid #1877f2;
  }

  input[type=password] {
    border: 2px solid #d9d9d9;
  }
  
  
.new_account_box{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    display: flex;
    
}

.dialog_box{
width: 27%;
height: 65%;
box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%), 0 8px 16px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);
margin: auto;
display: grid;
grid-template-rows: repeat(7,1fr);
background-color: white;

}

#new_item_1{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    padding: 20px;
    height: fit-content;
}

#item_1_1{
    color: black;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 900;
}

#item_1_1::after{
    content: "It's quick and easy";
    display: block;
    margin-top: 2%;
    font-size: .8rem;
    color: #606770;
}

#item_1_2{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
#item_1_2 img{
    cursor: pointer;
}

#item_1_2 img{
    height: 30%;
}

#new_item_2{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2,auto);
}

.names{
    border: 2px solid #d9d9d9;
    width: 80%;
    height: 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-self: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #f1f3f4;
    
}

.input_fields{
    border: 2px solid #d9d9d9;
    width: 85%;
    height: 55%;
    display: flex;
    justify-self: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #f1f3f4;
}

#item_5_1{
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    font-size: .8rem;
    color: #606770;
}


#new_item_6{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1.5fr
}

#item_6_1{
    margin-left: 5%;
    color: #606770;
    font-size: .9rem;
}

#item_6_2{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
    width: 95%;
    justify-self: center;
    gap: 2%;
}

.item_6_2_content{
    border: 2px solid #d9d9d9;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-left: 15%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr
}
.checkmark{
    width: 70%;
    height: 70%;
    background-color: #1877f2;
    display: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    
}

.gender{
    
    width: 20%;
    height: 30%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-top: 8%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    align-self: center;
    
}

.gender input:checked + .checkmark{
    display: inline-block;
}

.gender input{
    display: none;
}

.gender_text{
    /* border: 2px solid black; */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: 10px;
    
}

#new_item_7{
    background-color: #42b72a;
    width: 40%;
    display: flex;
    margin: auto;
    height: 50%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
}

#button_text{
    color: white;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin: auto;
    border: 0px;
}

input:focus{
    outline: none;
}
#new_item_7{
    cursor: pointer;
}
#new_item_7:hover{
    background-color: #30ce11;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you are calling a function that is named 'new_account' when the user submits login information. Is that right? What does it do?

Comment: it opens a pop up window where user fill details if he/she want to create a new account its just hidden by display:none

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `type="submit"` inside

```
<button class="right_side_items" id="item_6"  
type="submit" onclick="new_account()">
    Create New Account
</button>
```

And, also, move the button **out of the form**, as it is not a part of it.

Comment: Thanks your solution is correct but when i runned it it was still throwing the same error and then i saw that the button was inside the form and thats why it was going to the same route even after removing 'submit' but thanks your solution really helped

Comment: Oh thanks for pointing that out. I'll edit my answer.